# xpath: Is there a way to get all the children's text in xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm using the xpath engine on Firefox. I have html:

```
<span>
   <b>prefix one</b> not bold part
</span>
<span>
   prefix two not bold part
</span>
```

I want all the `span`s that have child text that start with "prefix one".

I tried the xpath:

```
//span[starts-with(child::text(), "prefix one")]
```

but this doesn't work because the `b` tag is interfering. How do you solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know that spans is not nested into other spans you can try this:

```
//span[ starts-with( descendant-or-self::*/text(),"prefix one" ) ]
```

`descendant-or-self::*/text(),` should return all text nodes which are in this subtree. I don't know how `starts-with()` exactly works but I suppose when some of `text()` nodes in subtree starts with "prefix one" that condition is true

Comment: This is equivalent to `//span[starts-with(., 'prefix one')]` or, more robust, `//span[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'prefix one')]`

Answer (score -2):

```
<xsl:template match="span">
<xsl:if test="contains(.,'prefix one')">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```