# Extracting nested text from html using xpath

Tags: java, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract textual content from a html page that looks something like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="section">
      Lorem <a href="..." class="link">ipsum</a> 
      dolor <a href="..." class="link">sit</a> amet, 
      consectetur <a href="..." class="link">adipiscing</a> elit
    </div>

    <div class="section">
      sed do <a href="..." class="link">eiusmod</a> tempor 
      incididunt <a href="..." class="link">ut</a> labore 
      et <a href="..." class="link">dolore</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want to extract the text portion:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
```

My XPath (2.0) expression is `//*[contains(@class, 'section')]`. When I evaluate it using `javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression`, I only retrieve the text that's outside the links:

```
Lorem dolor amet, consectetur elit, sed do tempor incididunt labore et
```

I haven't used XPath before - is there a better expression to extract the full text? thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). Using XML libraries to evaluate an xpath depend on well formed XML/HTML files. HTML is sometimes not due to browsers can catch some structure errors. If you really want to use an XML library for this have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999761/xpath-is-there-a-way-to-get-all-the-childrens-text-in-xpath). Hope this helps. Greets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression returns a complete XML element. Your processor then returns this as string by converting a the XML element to a text, so basically the same as you would have executed

```
//*[contains(@class, 'section')]/text()
```

In contrast, you can get all text elements also in the children by using the `string()` function:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'section')]/string()
```

Another way, as pointed out by Mathias Müller in the comments, would be to use

```
//*[contains(@class, 'section')]//text()
```

which returns all descendant-or-self text elements.

Comment: The correct answer, +1. Perhaps it would be insightful to add that `//*[contains(@class, 'section')]//text()` [does also work](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTz9)?

Comment: @MathiasMüller I updated my answer accordingly - Thanks for pointing this out.